# Is F# better than C# in scenarios where you need complete parallelism in parts of an application?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, parallel-processing

Is F# better than C# in scenarios where you need complete parallelism in parts of an application?

My main language is C# and I am writing an app where the core functionality built on top of the app (C#) has to be and planned to be very parallel.

Am I better of implementing these classes in F#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd look at the Parallel Extensions that's being developed by [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/concurrency/default.aspx).

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2009/02/23/adding-parallel-extensions-to-f.aspx

Comment: I thought so too. hoping it is backed into the 2010 release

Answer (score 5):

If you just need to process sets of data in parallel, the ParallelFX are very handy. They'll take a lot of pain out of doing it manually in C#.

But if the code has a lot of asynchronous code, F#'s async monad makes it vastly easier than can be done in C#. If you're looking at a lot of BeginXXX/EndXXX or the dreaded XXXAsync/XXXCompletedEvent code, then F# will be a major win.

Otherwise, you'll just have the general gains of F# over C#.

Comment: Having to write such code by hand really seines indirekt intothe thinking behind continuation passing style

Comment: Async is built in C# next release, [check it out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360).

Answer (score 2):

there are two ways of making things parallel, both of them work very well in F#.

- As Josh already mentioned, there is a Parallel Extensions library. This make it extremely easy to parallelize processing of some data structures - especially immutable data structures that you'll often use in F#. So, combining Paraallel Extensions with F# is the right way to go. This will be discussed in my [upcoming real-world F# book](http://manning.com/petricek), but I'm making the [source code](http://www.functional-programming.net/sources.aspx) available. This is covered in chapter 14 and the source for it should be available soon.
- For some problems, you can use message-passing concurrency, which is an appealing alternative to shared memory. You can find some information about this in a free [chapter from Don Syme's book](http://download.microsoft.com/download/b/b/6/bb666ebe-e643-496f-b290-03527d157b47/Expert.F.Sharp_Ch13_8504Syme.pdf). It'll be covered in my book as well (Chapter 13 & 16).
- By combining message-passing concurrency with asynchronous workflows, you can get an excellent way for writing programs that cannot be easily parallelized using Parallel extensions (i.e. they need to share some information & also use asynchronous non-blocking operations (such as downloading from the internet))

Answer (score 2):

According to this demonstration by Luca Bolognese, the ease of implementing parallelism is   one of F#'s stronger points. At around 53 minute mark on, it gets quite impressive. Hope this helps a bit.
http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL11/

Answer (score 2):

F# has many advantages over C# in general and these play an equal role in the context of parallel programming but there is nothing about the F# programming language that makes it substantially more suitable for parallel programming.

In particular, there is a myth that shunning side effects and going purely functional is a panacea for parallelism but this is nonsense. You can make purely functional programs burn more cores more easily but getting competitive absolute performance and speedup on a multicore is an unsolved problem.

As others have already said, you will almost certainly want to use the Task Parallel Library that is now part of .NET 4. Note that the Visual F# 2010 standard library includes several functions that use the TPL, such as `Array.Parallel.map`.

Answer (score 1):

F# is mostly free of side-effects so yes, but you wouldn't want to implement a UI in it. On the flip side, there will be a lot of parallel functionality built in to the next version of C# via LINQ.

You will also have to weigh your training requirements and the fact that F# is not yet RTM and won't be until late this year.

Comment: @Abel, I hope it has gone RTM by now. My comment was from 3 years ago!

Answer (score 0):

F# makes certain approaches better (e.g. native message support), but you can do it in C# if you minimise (or better, eliminate) mutable state.

As noted in other answers, .NET libraries are going to get a big boost in this way soon with the parallel extensions. These will have, however, exactly the same lack of scalability if you start using locks.

Comment: Minimizing or eliminating mutable state is a bad idea in the context of parallel programming.

Comment: @JonH: Are you sure you meant that? Most would say avoiding mutable state (and therefore the need for locks) is a *good* idea when you want concurrency.

Comment: Avoiding mutable state is often a good idea in the context of concurrency because it usually greatly simplifies the solution. But concurrency is not parallelism and, in particular, parallelism is all about throughput performance but eliminating state often not only severely degrades throughput performance but also increases cache complexity and that destroys scalability on multicores. So purity and concurrency often go well together but purity and parallelism very rarely go well together.